# MasterPage in children subsite

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, master-page

Can I change master page only in subsite without selecting `"Specify a master page to be used by this site and all sites that inherit from it:"` in "Site Settings" -> "Look and feel" -> "Master Page"?

Comment: Just so you know, Site Settings->Look and Feel -> Master page only affects subsites created after you make the change.  You have to tick the "Reset all subsites" box in order to force existing subsites to use the new master page selection.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can through one of the below methods.

1. **Using SharePoint PowerShell**

   ```
   $web = Get-SPWeb siteurl
   $web.MasterUrl = "masterpagerelativeurl"
   $web.Update()
   $web.Dispose()
   ```
2. **Using SharePoint Designer**,

   - Open your Site using SharePoint Designer.
   - Go to MaterPage section in the left side> Right Click on your Master Page > Select `Set Master Page as Default`